# OpenGL Texture Loading issue with images that Crossed each other

Tags: c, opengl

Problem Image:

[image: Problem Image]

I found some depart from image. I Think Texture location is problem, But I can't Solve this issue

My Code :

```
GLuint LoadTexture(const char * filename, int width, int height)

GLuint texture;
unsigned char * data;
FILE * file;

file = fopen(filename, "r");

if (file == NULL) return 0;

data = (unsigned char *)malloc(width * height * 3);
fread(data, width * height * 3, 1, file);
fclose(file);

// RGB
for (int i = 0; i < width * height; ++i)
{
    int index = i * 3;
    unsigned char B, R;
    B = data[index];
    R = data[index + 2];

    data[index] = R;
    data[index + 2] = B;
}

glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_BLEND); // GL_REPLACE에서 교체했음
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP); // GL_CLAMP
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

return texture;
```

and

```
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_image[2]);
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2i(0, 0); glVertex3f(-32, -32, 0);
    glTexCoord2i(0, 1); glVertex3f(-32, 32, 0);
    glTexCoord2i(1, 1); glVertex3f(32, 32, 0);
    glTexCoord2i(1, 0); glVertex3f(32, -32, 0);
    glEnd();
```

This is the My first question here
I dunno this is correct, but thank you.

Comment: What is the format of the texture? are you sure that each pixel has 24 bits? What is the original image file?

Comment: Its Bmp and RGB24

Comment: But a BMP-file has a file header!

Comment: I found the header contain width,height,resolution,pixel bits.
if this is right it is 64, 64, 64X64, 24bits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Windows Bitmap](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Bitmap) file has a file header of 54 bytes. I this header is the format of the file encoded.

If you know, that the file format is 24 bit RGB, then you can simply skip the header.

```
data = (unsigned char *)malloc(width * height * 3 + 54);
fread(data, width * height * 3 + 54, 1, file);
fclose(file);

.....

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data+54);
```

---

Further note, by default, each row of a texture is assumed to be aligned to 4 bytes.
At a 24bit RGB BMP image, each texel needs 24 bits or 3 byte and the pixels are tightly packed especially the rows of the texture.
This means that the alignment of 4 bytes for the start of a line of the texture is disregarded (except 3 times the width of the texture is divisible by 4 without a remaining).

This not any problem in your case because you texture has a with of 64 pixel and 64*3 is dividable by 4. But if the number of bytes per row would not be dividable by 4, you would have to change the alignment to 1.

This means the [`GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPixelStore.xhtml) parameter has to be set to 1, before loading a tightly packed texture to the GPU ([`glTexImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml)).
Otherwise an offset of 0-3 bytes per line is gained, at texture lookup. This would causes a continuously twisted or tilted texture.

```
glPixelStore(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data+54);
```

Answer (score 0):

One needs a naked GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE GL_RGB image, and that's probably not what that image is. `OpenGL` does not provide any file format support at all. You could save file as such using, eg, `GIMP`, but that will be a large file, (edit: uncompressed bitmap 24BPP, once you get past the BMP header, is one such format.) A more sustainable solution is to save the file in a known format and use a library to decompress it. Some of my favourites are,

- https://lodev.org/lodepng/
- https://keyj.emphy.de/nanojpeg/